# How can I make the layouts of an application made in python using the kivymd library adapt to different types of screens?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I created an application using kivymd, but it has a detail that does not interfere, but makes the interface strange. All the components that are in the app (labels, images, textinputs, buttons) work perfectly and in the correct places on my phone, but when I test it on another phone with a screen size bigger or smaller than mine, the components end up being in places either above, or below the original position. And besides, the application's texts are in a standard size, and do not adjust to different types of screens, making the texts look small on larger screens.

I tried looking through the documentation, but I couldn't find anything that solved my problems.

Comment: Have a look at the [size_hint documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.1.0/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=size_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x) and the [dimensions documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.1.0/api-kivy.metrics.html?highlight=font_size#dimensions).

Comment: I just looked through the documentation and found two units that I think will do, the Dp and Sp. From what I've seen Dp is used for widgets and Sp for text fonts, but I'm not sure how to use them. Could you explain to me how to use each of these units?

Comment: The linked documentation includes examples.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve my problem.